# Android: равномерное заполнение строки в GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Как видно на изображении с [официальных гайдлайнов Android](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html), содержимое каждой строки `BottomSheet` распределено равномерно по 3 штуки. Но можно ли реализовать такое выравнивание с помощью `GridLayout`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приведённой ниже вёрстке первая и последняя иконки (с подписями) выравнены правильно, а вот отцентрировать среднюю - не получается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
             <!-- ... -->
         />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
             <!-- ... -->
         />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
             <!-- ... -->
         />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Попробуйте у `LinearLayout` `weight=1`, `gravity=center`, `layout_width=0dp`. И кстати весь ваш этот линер лейаут можно заменить одним текствью с картинкой - [Compound Drawables](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/compound-drawable/).

Comment: Попробовал - всё исчезло. Про CompoundDrawables знаю, но можно ли управлять картинкой, когда она является частью Textview? Например, устанавливать ей размеры, margin, прозрачность?

Comment: Ну все эти параметры можно установить уже у самого файла картинки. Вы же не будете менять их программно.

Comment: @eugeneek, то есть, у самого файла? Как Вы установите эти параметры, например, у png-изображения, если оно является частью `compoundDrawable?`

Comment: С каким параметром проблема? Размер? Прозрачность? Отступы? Всё это можно установить у png картинки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен параметр `layout_columnWeight`. В `GridView` он добавлен с API 21. Если нужна поддержка ранних версий, можете использовать грид вью из саппорт библиотеки `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    grid:columnCount="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1">
        <ImageView
           <!-- ... -->
            />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1">
        <ImageView
            <!-- ... -->
        />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1">
        <ImageView
            <!-- ... -->
            />
        <TextView
            <!-- ... -->
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Одного `grid:layout_columnWeight` хватило, чтобы всё заработало... Спасибо Вам за ответ!